# Cannot create new Flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to create a new flutter project and start the fist app. When open android studio and click "create new Flutter application", set project name, then click next. At this point, Android Studio freezes.

1. Click create Flutter App
2. Set project name and select flutter sdk path.
3. select design pattern
4. then click finish

Android studio freezes when I get to the fourth step.

[image: creating new flutter app page]

Comment: what's your machine details, and what does command flutter doctor says, please include them in the  question

Comment: Be ensure that you have android studio upto date..

Comment: @Sachin All problems solved after android studio update. thanks

Comment: Its okk @TalhaÇelik

Answer (score 0):

That might happening because of your system configuration. This is the minimum system requirement Google decided for installing android studio:
[image]

If your system doesn't meet the minimum above try Installing Visual Studio Code (VSCode) from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download). And try to configure your first project through [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code) tutorials.

Comment: MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)  - 1,8 GHz Intel Core i5 - 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: are you still facing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a new project in terminal..

```
flutter create <name>
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: flutter command is not found in my terminal. I don't was install using homebrew. I was just only install to android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter doesn't tell you, but if you try to run any flutter command such as "create project" or "doctor" without administrator rights your CLI or IDE will freeze.

Try running Android Studio as administrator.